# Square values of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I need to know if there is an efficient algorithm for knowing the following problem?

Consider a monic polynomial $f$ of degree $3$ on the finite field $F_q$ when $q$ is the power of a prime number.
Suppose S is the set of values of $f$ for all elements of $F_q$.

$\begin{gathered}
  f\left( x \right) = {x^3} + a{x^2} + bx + c \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
  S = \left\{ {f\left( x \right)|x \in {F_q}\,} \right\} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $

An algorithm that tells me in good time that the number of squares S in Fq is greater or the number of not-squares S.

That is, in fact, the output of the algorithm is true or false

Comment: The equation $y^2=f(x)$ describes an elliptic curve (barring a double root of $f$). Answering your question tells us something non-trivial about the number of points on that elliptic curve. There is a polynomial time algorithm due to Schoof-Elkies-Atkin for finding the exact number. If the hairy algebra won't deter you that might work. I don't know whether it can answer your coarses question sooner. I am somewhat skeptical, because SEA is based on CRT.combining data modulo several primes, and the last prime to be handled may have a large impact.

Comment: And that double root, if it exists, gives a square factor making the decision easy.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks Dear Jyrki for your kindly comments. I have seen this algorithm But as you said, we have to count all the Elliptic Curve Point (all squares) and it will take a long time.
I want to get to the answer in less time, and this algorithm will just say that there are more squares or non-square.

Comment: I understand. Surely SEA feels like overkill.